# Hiding and Toggle 3 different Div Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have three different span.class's that I want to show content for whenever they are clicked. Those div classes are:

```
<div id="one">
            <span class="aboutme"> <p>About me</p></span>
            <span class="skills"> <p>Skills</p></span>
            <span class="goals"><p>My Goals</p></span>
       </div>
```

I do want the span.aboutme to show on page load up, but hide whenever these other classes are clicked.

here's what I have so far in jsfiddle, but it's not working out.

https://jsfiddle.net/ispykenny/m4n8fzfp/

```
<div class="thirdwrapper">
     <div class="wrapperthree">
       <div id="one">
            <span class="aboutme"> <p>About me</p></span>
            <span class="skills"> <p>Skills</p></span>
            <span class="goals"><p>My Goals</p></span>
       </div>



        <div id="two">
        <span class="aboutmecontent">
        <p>content for about me
        </span>
        <span class="skillscontent"> <p>content for skills</p> </span>
        <span class="goalscontent"> <p>cotent for goals</p></span>
    </div>
      </div>
        </div>
          </div>

    .thirdwrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 400px;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;

    }
    .wrapperthree{
        max-width: 1050px;
        min-height: 400px;
        min-width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .wrapperthree p{
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;


    }
    #one{
        max-width: 525px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 400px;
        border:1px solid white;
        float: left;
        font-size: 80px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 60px;
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    }

    #one p{
        text-align:center;
        width:400px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;


    }

    #two{
        max-width: 525px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 60px;

    }
    span.aboutme p {
        background-color:#666;

    }
    .skills p{
        background-color: #999;
    }
    .goals p{
        background-color: #333;
    }
    .skillscontent p{
        display: none;
    }
    .goalscontent p{
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you basically just need to check which class is being clicked, and first hide them, and then show the one you would actually like to show (if the classes always match up.)

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4n8fzfp/3/

```
$('#one span').click(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    var className = that[0].className;
    console.log($(this)[0].className);

    $('#two').children('span').children('p').hide();


    $('#two').find('.' + className + 'content p').show();


})
```

Comment: Hey Jesse, thanks so much for your help. This was what I needed.

Comment: No problem :) If it helped you, you should accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want tabs. This can be easily achieved using `jQuery`:

https://jsfiddle.net/m4n8fzfp/4/

What you're basically doing is associating each content `span` with it's appropriate link using the `data-tab` directive and adding and removing the `current` `class` with the appropriate `display` attribute.